# Movement lags on mobile, but in editor is good

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a square that I move by using this coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator Move(int steps)
{
    var shape = particleSystem.shape;

    for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        if (canMove(dir))
        {
            isMoving = true;
            shape.rotation = new Vector3(0f, yParts(), 0f);
            particleSystem.Play();
            float elapsedTime = 0;
            startPos = transform.position;
            targetPos = startPos + dir;

            while(elapsedTime < timeToMove)
            {
                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, targetPos, (elapsedTime / timeToMove));
                elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
            transform.position = targetPos;
            isMoving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In editor it works fine, but on mobile movement it´s not smooth.

It isn't a fps problem, because I have particles on the scene and they show correctly.

I thought the trouble is that I am adding `Time.deltaTime`, but i'm doing it more often then `Time.deltaTime`. So I tried to change `yield return null` with `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();`. It makes better, but i am not sure.

Anyway result is different from the one in the editor. Also i tried to change `yield return null` with `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate`, and it didn't work smoothly in editor and mobile. After that I tried to change rate of `fixedupdate` in preferences form `0.2` to `0.1`, and it became as it was in the beginning.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, is it a requirement to yield for `WaitForEndOfFrame`?

Comment: Hey, It last that I tried and as I wrote, it seems to be better with this, then just using the yield return null. There is no need to use it for me)

Comment: I think you may see this tutorial: [Smooth Motion in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtV8JEIq0Ng), it's recommended to use interpolation and compute your movements in the `FixedUpdate` method

Comment: Very usefull guide, thanks. But it not for my situation as i see. I tried to use interpolate scripts from guide, it didn't work. I found out that unity has own interpolate system for rigidbodies and tried it to, but result is one - in editor and pc build it works smootly and fine, on mobile - low framerate for square movement, but good for particles.